# get only updated item from firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database in which I stored various inquiries. Each inquiry has a name and an email. What I want is whenever a new item is added or existed item is updated, firebase would return with only that user. Right now it returns all the users list.

```
componentDidMount()
    {
        firebaseDB.child("inquiries").on("value",snapshot =>
        {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            this.setState({inquiries:snapshot.val()});
        })

    }
```

Comment: It is returning whole inquiry list as you are watching for the whole collection inquires. You add key for newly created or existing user to watch for particular document. Like firebaseDB.ref("inquiries/"+ key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to listen to `child_` events, which get called when something happens on the level under `inquiries.

For example, to respond to additions and changed, you'd do:

```
firebaseDB.child("inquiries").on("child_added", (snapshot, previousChildKey) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key+" was added after "+previousChildKey+": "+snapshot.val());
})
firebaseDB.child("inquiries").on("child_changed",snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key+" was changed");
})
```

With these events you can then perform the minimal update to the UI.